# Воксельная графика и где её можно най и и спользовать?

Tags: any

Мне интересна технология вокселей, я слышал что она млжет соперничать с полигонной графикой. Мне бы было крайне интересно знать как её испльзовать и где её найти.
Я могу предположить, что большенство даже и не слышало об этом.
В этом [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3Ets6bWjEQ&t=29s), используется эта технология. Уже реализованный проект "teardown" реализован с использованием воксельной графики и полной разрушаемостью. Я слышал, что технология вокселей, по сравнению с полигонной графикой абсолютно разные, даже производительность, говорят у вокселной графики больше, чем у полигонной.
Меня интересует информация, которая позволит мне создать хоть что-то воксельное.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как воксельная графика в настоящий момент вообще не конкурент полигональной (с учётом поддержки видеокартами последней) и использовалась в основном на заре 3D (90е года) (про всякие научные вещи не говорим, которые еще с 60х тянутся)

Хотя в некоторых моментах воксели по сравнению с полигоном давали определённый выигрыш,

Например трассировка лучей в реальном времени очень хорошо работала на шарообразных вокселях (очень легкие рассчёты были)

Воксельную графику используют там, где изначально присутствуют воксели - например при сканировании изображений (например, МРТ и постройка трёхмерного изображения), хотя сейчас опять таки воксельное изображение легко переводится в полигональное